# how would i play a large list of mp3 and wav files while showing the name of it on the screen with ffmpeg

Tags: python, audio, video, ffmpeg

i've been attempting to make a video that is autogenerated using ffmpeg that plays a list of audios and while they are playing it shows the name of the audio file on the screen. i have no idea how to use ffmpeg and i abused ai for the provided script, but it's stupid and doesn't know how to properly reencode the file fixing the bugs at the end which cause the audio to only be on the left channel for no reason and then eventually cutting out.

```
import os
import subprocess

def create_combined_video(audio_folder, output_path):
    # Get a list of audio files in the specified folder
    audio_files = []
    for filename in os.listdir(audio_folder):
        if filename.endswith(".mp3") or filename.endswith(".wav"):
            audio_files.append(os.path.join(audio_folder, filename))

    # Sort the audio files alphabetically
    audio_files.sort()

    # Create a folder to store the temporary image frames
    temp_frames_folder = "temp_frames"
    os.makedirs(temp_frames_folder, exist_ok=True)

    # Generate the image frames with the corresponding audio file names
    for index, audio_file in enumerate(audio_files):
        name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(audio_file))[0]
        image_path = os.path.join(temp_frames_folder, f"{index+1:06d}.jpg")

        # Use FFmpeg to create the image frame with text overlay
        ffmpeg_cmd = f'ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i color=c=white:s=720x480:d=1 -vf "drawtext=text=\'{name}\':fontcolor=black:fontsize=36:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -vframes 1 "{image_path}"'
        subprocess.run(ffmpeg_cmd, shell=True)

    # Generate a text file containing the image file names for each audio
    image_names_path = "image_names.txt"
    with open(image_names_path, "w") as file:
        for index, audio_file in enumerate(audio_files):
            image_path = os.path.join(temp_frames_folder, f"{index+1:06d}.jpg")
            duration = get_audio_duration(audio_file)
            file.write(f"file '{image_path}'\nduration {duration}\n")

    # Generate a text file containing the audio file names
    audio_names_path = "audio_names.txt" 
    with open(audio_names_path, "w") as file:
        for audio_file in audio_files:
            file.write(f"file '{audio_file}'\n")

    # Re-encode the audio files with a common codec (AAC)
    reencoded_audio_folder = "reencoded_audio"
    os.makedirs(reencoded_audio_folder, exist_ok=True)
    for index, audio_file in enumerate(audio_files):
        reencoded_audio_file = os.path.join(reencoded_audio_folder, f"{index:03d}.m4a")
        ffmpeg_cmd = f'ffmpeg -y -i "{audio_file}" -c:a aac "{reencoded_audio_file}"'
        subprocess.run(ffmpeg_cmd, shell=True)

    # Generate a text file containing the re-encoded audio file names
    reencoded_audio_names_path = "reencoded_audio_names.txt"
    with open(reencoded_audio_names_path, "w") as file:
        for index, audio_file in enumerate(audio_files):
            reencoded_audio_file = os.path.join(reencoded_audio_folder, f"{index:03d}.m4a")
            file.write(f"file '{reencoded_audio_file}'\n")

    # Use FFmpeg to generate the video with the image frames and re-encoded audio
    ffmpeg_cmd = f'ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i "{image_names_path}" -f concat -safe 0 -i "{reencoded_audio_names_path}" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=720:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=720:480" -c:a aac -shortest "{output_path}"'
    subprocess.run(ffmpeg_cmd, shell=True)

    # Clean up temporary files and folders
    os.remove(image_names_path)
    os.remove(audio_names_path)
    for image_file in os.listdir(temp_frames_folder):
        os.remove(os.path.join(temp_frames_folder, image_file))
    os.rmdir(temp_frames_folder)
    for audio_file in os.listdir(reencoded_audio_folder):
        os.remove(os.path.join(reencoded_audio_folder, audio_file))
    os.rmdir(reencoded_audio_folder)

def get_audio_duration(audio_file): 
    # Use FFprobe to get the duration of the audio file
    ffprobe_cmd = f'ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "{audio_file}"'
    result = subprocess.run(ffprobe_cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
    duration = float(result.stdout.strip())
    return duration

# Usage example
audio_folder = "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Sounds"
output_path = "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/output.mp4"
create_combined_video(audio_folder, output_path)
```

i've tried yelling at ai to fix the bug and all it does is break the script instead of doing what i asked it to, but i believe all it has to do is fix reencoding